# enjoy another stunning sunset 'over' a glass of assyrtiko

Tags: prepositions, word-meaning

This is from [a news article](https://edition.cnn.com/travel/article/santorini-volcano-kolumbo-scn/index.html).

> Santorini could one day be buried under a layer of ash once more. But
> for now – as visitors enjoy another stunning sunset **over** a glass of
> assyrtiko – the volcano keeps quiet.

I looked up the preposition '**over**' in [the Merriam-Webster dictionary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/over#dictionary-entry-2) and picked up two candidate meanings which may be appropriate here.

> 1 —used as a function word to indicate motion or situation in a
> position higher than or above another
>
> 7b —used as a function word to indicate the object of an expressed or
> implied occupation, activity, or concern

I am curious which of the two the meaning of 'over' is in the above context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The meaning of 'while doing something' is perhaps less clear in Merriam-Webster, but shown in Cambridge Dictionary thus:

> over preposition (DURING)
> during something, or while doing something:
> *I was in Seattle over the summer*
> ***Shall we discuss it over lunch/over a drink?***
> *They took/spent an hour over lunch (= their meal lasted an hour)*.

[Over (Cambridge Dictionary)](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/over)

Comment: Merriam-Webster's 7b captures this meaning. One of their examples is: "*met with advisers over lunch*"

Comment: I agree with @gotube, “over the summer” means merely “during, or throughout the summer.” By contrast, “over dinner” or “drinks,” “sushi,” or “a game of Scrabble” means a bit more. Note that all of these examples happen at a table; each of these objects of the preposition *over* is something that essentially happens or rests on the table while the participants converse, etc. (literally) overtop of it. So, now that I think of it, in this construction, *over* is something of a pun.

Answer (score 3):

The nuances of the meaning of "over" in your example aren't properly covered either by M-W or Cambridge.

The object of "over" with that function must be something both *below the subjects* and which *takes time to do*, like drinks, a meal or a board game. This means it carries *both* the meanings of "above" and "during".

While it's correct to say, "I was in Seattle over the summer", that's a different meaning of "over" because it just means *during* the summer, not *above* it.